# how can i publish a C# .net console app without the console?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using c#, .NET core 3.1, vs-code & windows 10

i want to publish my console application but ensure the console will not open when i run the built project. The current command i usually use to publish an app is:
`dot net publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`.

(yes, i know the .net command is writen that way, its the only way i could get this question to post)

I want the console to not open because i use a separate library to open a window for rendering.
I have already looked around and haven't found anything to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to change `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` to `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` in your csproj. Once you do that, your application won't open a console window.

Later on, if you want to open a console window for debugging or whatever you can PInvoke [AllocConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).